# How do I inserting a loop in an while, if-else statement in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to complete a sort of homework I have, which is supposed to ask for a decimal-number. If writen with . instead of , the text "You need to write your decimal-number with an (,) following Swedish standard".

Here I want the program to loop back, so the user will have to retry until the decimal-number is entered with an (,).

After this the program shall ask how many decimals you want to round it down to. But currently my program just put out text that you need to use , according to Swedish standard FOLLOWED by text "how many decimals do you want to round it down to" without looping the first statement if wrong.

I have currently tried changing a few things but it often leads to that the program crashes. I currently uses "else break;" on to places and the code is not completed but functional. More code is needed to complete my task, but currently stuck on the loop-issue

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double value1;
            int round1;

            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter a decimal-number: ");
                string StrValue = Console.ReadLine();

                bool success = Double.TryParse(StrValue, out value1);
                if (!success)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You need to use (,) as decimal-sign according to Swedish standard!"); //From here I want a loop if . is used instead of ,
                }

                Console.Write("With how many decimal-numbers do you want to round it down to?: ");
                string StrRound = Console.ReadLine();

                bool success1 = Int32.TryParse(StrRound, out round1);
                if (!success1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Only use whole numbers when rounding");
                }
                else break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I expected the program to loop after first statement, but I cant figure out why it doesn't and how I should fix this!

Comment: What you need is `continue` statement in the first `if`. It will start a new iteration of the loop. See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/continue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the if condition with a while loop, try this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double value1;
        int round1;

        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter a decimal-number: ");
            string StrValue = Console.ReadLine();

            bool success = Double.TryParse(StrValue, out value1);
            while (!success)
            {
                 Console.WriteLine("You need to use (,) as decimal-sign according to Swedish standard!"); //From here I want a loop if . is used instead of ,
                 StrValue = Console.ReadLine();
                 success = Double.TryParse(StrValue, out value1);
            }

            Console.Write("With how many decimal-numbers do you want to round it down to?: ");
            string StrRound = Console.ReadLine();

            bool success1 = Int32.TryParse(StrRound, out round1);
            if (!success1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Only use whole numbers when rounding");
            }
            else break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What if the second attempt is also failed?

Comment: This change worked for me. I can now continue my code and hopefully I can complete the rest of this task by myself. 
@tukaef You have a valid question that I probably will encounter soon, if any problems should appear I hope it can be helped more by you guys to solve!

Comment: You can just replace the second if condition with a similar while loop :)

Comment: @GalalHassan Thanks alot mate, this solved a "bug" and made the program run more like I wanted to.

Now I just need to figure out how to make "value1" being rounded down in decimals by the output of "round1". And since I try to make the program as functional as possible I also try to figure out how to prevent someone to choose a bigger rounding-number of decimals then entered as first decimal-number (unless it automatically turns ex 1,2 to 1,2000000 if 7 is entered as rounding number.